# Android studio with GIT - is it really GIT?

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

I have just started using Android Studio after a lull of several years - last used Eclipse for Android development. (All sorts of other grief with AS, but that is another story).

Confused about use of GIT.

I 'think' I have put the project under (local) GIT through the AS IDE, but when I start looking directly at the project files and directories under C:\users\\StudioProjects, I can find neither a .git directory, nor a .gitignore file.

This seems very strange. Is Android Studio really using GIT, or just something that looks like GIT but isn't?

Comment: It's Git. Do you have show hidden files enabled?

Comment: Yes, hidden files are enabled.

Comment: Ah, found it - cannot think how I missed it. No default .gitignore though.